# Set an element after a dynamically appended json key inside the dom using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have a json as follows -

```
const data = [{
  "testData": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "three"
  }
}]
```

I am setting the key value pair after a certain div as follows-

```
$.getJSON("json-file.json",
function (data) {
  const json = data.testData;
  for (const key in json) {
    var listItem = `<div><p>${key}</p><p>${json[key]}</p></div>`;
    $("#selectordiv").after(listItem);
  }
}
```

I want to set a p tag after the key "two" in the dom. I am doing something like -

```
$.getJSON("json-file.json",
function (data) {
  const json = data.testData;
  for (const key in json) {
    var listItem = `<div><p>${key}</p><p>${json[key]}</p></div>`;
    $("#selectordiv").after(listItem);
    if(key == "two"){
      $('this').after("<p>test</p>");
    })
  }      
  })
```

This give me an error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "This give me an error" - What is the error?

Comment: the parenthesis are wrong in the last snippet

Comment: @NickParsons "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"

Comment: @Greedo Hi have edited my code.

Comment: There is still an extra `)` after the `if` closing

Comment: I believe you have a lot of other data in your JSON as well not just one array of `object` ? Just wondering

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  hey ! Yes I have a long list of data coming from an API.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping In this case if I want to select that <p> tag where the key is "two" , how can I do that ? ( I don't want to select using index because in the real scenario , there are many entries. ) What should I write in the $ selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many syntax error in this snippet.. you can solve them just by executing the code in the console :)

Here is a solution:

```js
const data = [{
  "testData": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "three"
  }
}]

function compile(data) {
  const json = data[0].testData;
  for (const key in json) {
    var listItem = `<div><p>${key}</p><p>${json[key]}</p></div>`;
    $("#selectordiv").append(listItem);
    if(key == "two"){
      $("#selectordiv").append("<p>test</p>");
    }
 }      
}

compile(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selectordiv"></div>
```

Comment: hey Thanks ! I thought appending the p tag would add it after the third item - "three" i.e. at the end ( going by the definition )  . But this worked ! Thanks ! :)